# TFS Team Explorer Stand Alone With VS 2008 Installed

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

Does anyone know how you can install/run the TFS Team Explorer in stand alone mode when Visual Studio 2008 is installed on the same machine?

Additional Information:  I should have been a little more clear in my question.  I'm trying to access the Work Items.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The TFS Team Explorer will always integrate with a version of Visual Studio (apart from Express) if it is installed and there is no way of running it stand-alone.

If you install the [TFS 2008 Power Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/teamsystem/bb980963.aspx), then you can have it so that you get Windows Explorer integration for TFS which many people enjoy.  You might also want to look at [Team System Web Access](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=136577) to provide a mechanism for accessing TFS from just a web browser (but obviously doesn't include full version control capabilities)

Finally, the company I work for has a completely standalone TFS client called [Teamprise Explorer](http://www.teamprise.com/products/explorer/) that is implemented in Java, however this is a commercial product.

Hope that helps,

Martin.

Comment: The Windows Explorer integration from the Power Tools is great and is very helpful.

I took a look at the Teamprise Explorer; really nice.  But, being a Visual Studio user I just didn't see much need for it.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is that there really isn't a standalone version.  When you install VS Team Explorer on a machine without Visual Studio, the installer will install a Visual Studio shell.  Then, when you run Team Explorer in standalone mode, you are actually running a Visual Studio shell.

Martin had a good point about [Team System Web Access](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=136577), which probably would do the job nicely.  Plus it has the added benefit that it allows non Visual Studio users access to work items.  But, it was decided that it was too much trouble to get permission to install it here (working for the US Army can have its issues).

My solution for now is to run another instance of Visual Studio and access the Team Explorer tools from there.